# Class scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter is deprecated, cannot find the alternative

Tags: scala

I'm using `scala 2.10_RC2`

I see that `scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter` in `scala-compiler.jar` is deprecated. The interpreter works fine, but I'm concerned that it may disappear in the near future.

I can't find anything on the net about the alternative, any information regarding it will be much appreciated

Comment: `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.shell.Scripted` in Scala 2.13.9, `dotty.tools.repl.ScriptEngine` in Scala 3.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [docs for the nightly](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter) you will find the recommendation to use the classes in [scala.tools.nsc.interpreter](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.package) package and use the class [ILoop](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop).

Comment: Thanks so much for that. But where is the recommendation to use ILoop in the docs? I can't find anything about it

Comment: It says "Use a class in the scala.tools.nsc.interpreter package", how do you know that's ILoop?

Comment: Oh, looking at the sources.

Comment: Sorry I'm being annoyingly persistent about this, but you actually looked through all the source files in scala.tools.nsc.interpreter package and found ILoop to be the replacement?! Firstly, you're amazingly tenacious and secondly, this looks like a horrible way of documenting by the Scala maintainers and I'm wondering if this sort of thing repeats itself in other places as well i.e. riddles left behind to keep the users guessing about which class to use and how to use it x-(

Comment: Check the scala shell script. You will end up looking at http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner which processes the cmd line flags and invokes ILoop